# Unclear threads' behaviour (working with UI) in android app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, handler

guys. There is a problem about threads in my android app. initializeGame() is the main method :

```
public void initializeGame()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new onePoint());
        thread.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

class, where i'm describing the thread :

```
class onePoint implements Runnable {
        (...)
        public void run() {
            (...)

            setBackgroundColorOnButton(...); 
            while (...) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                (...)

                if (...) {
                    setOpacityOnButton(...);
                }
            }
        }
```

Where it is "(...)", there is just a work with variables.
You see, there are two methods : setBackgroundColorOnButton() and setOpacityOnButton().

I'll show them :

```
void setBackgroundColorOnButton(int id, int num) {
              int color = Color.parseColor("#cccaca");

                switch (num) {
                    case 1: color = Color.RED; break;
                    case 2: color = Color.parseColor("#FF4F38"); break;
                    case 3: color = Color.YELLOW; break;
                    case 4: color = Color.GREEN; break;
                    case 5: color = Color.BLUE; break;
                    case 6: color = Color.parseColor("#09256C"); break;
                    case 7: color = Color.parseColor("#690069"); break;
                }

                final int col = color;

                Message message = backgroundColorOnButton.obtainMessage();
                message.obj = new int[] {id, col};
                backgroundColorOnButton.sendMessage(message);
            }

    void setOpacityOnButton(int id, final int opacity) {
            Message message = opacityOnButton.obtainMessage();
            message.obj = new int[] {id, opacity};
            opacityOnButton.sendMessage(message);
        }
```

In this methods i'm sending messages to 2 handlers, which are described in onCreate() :

```
backgroundColorOnButton = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                int[] a = (int[]) msg.obj;

                Button btn = (Button) findViewById(a[0]);

                GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) btn.getBackground();
                drawable.setColor(a[1]);

            }
        };

        opacityOnButton = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              int[] a = (int[]) msg.obj;

              Button btn = (Button) findViewById(a[0]);

              if (a[1] != 0) {
                  btn.setText(Integer.toString(a[1]));
              }
              else {
                  btn.setText("");
              }
          }
        };
```

In method onCreate() i also create ui elements.

My problem: in method onCreate() i call initializeGame(), and i need to see ui changing after app starts, but i don't see it for 5 seconds. It is a white screen during 5 seconds and then ui's starting to change. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Uhm... because you have a 5-second sleep in initializeGame(), which you call on the main thread?

Comment: @snilddolkow but i start thread  **before** the sleep

Comment: @DeathCookies I do not know about Android development. But maybe the `initializeGame` method is called in some _event handling thread_, which is also responsible for other events like color changing. You are actually suspending this thread. It would be the as the EDT in Swing. As said, I do not really know that.

Comment: DeathCookies: Yeah, but your sleep code does not run in that thread. Your main thread starts a new thread, then it sleeps for 5 seconds. @Seelenvirtuose: Exactly, and in Android, we call that the "main thread" or, less commonly, the "UI thread".

Comment: @snilddolkow i'm not good at english, can you explain you words simpler?

Comment: Your main thread goes `start(); sleep();`. It starts a thread, but once it's started, it continues running the code in method `initializeGame()`. Meanwhile, the newly started thread simply calls `onePoint.run()`.

Comment: Most GUI frameworks do all of the event processing/screen updating in a single thread.  I don't know what Android calls it, but Swing calls it the _event dispatch thread_ (EDT).  If your `initializeGame()` is called by the EDT, or maybe (I don't know Android) by a thread that will _become_ the EDT, then your application will be unresponsive until it returns.  Doesn't matter what your other threads may be doing.

Comment: As Snild said, the Thread.sleep does not sleep your worker Thread but your main Thread (UI Thread), so your UI is not displayed for 5 seconds.